# Sum array of vectors with cuda

Tags: vector, cuda, sum

I need to find average for thousands (20,000+) images represented by *unsigned short* arrays. Could you please check me, it looks for me that this code is not optimal:

**my kernel:**

```
__global__ void VecAdd(unsigned short *A, float *B,  unsigned int Size, float div){

  register float divider = div;
  register int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if ( idx < Size) {
   B[ idx ] = (float) A[idx] /  divider + B[idx];
  }
  //__syncthreads();
}
```

**kernel wrapper:**

```
void kernel_wrapper(unsigned short* pixels1, float* pixels2,  unsigned int length, float div)
{
    unsigned short* deviceData1;
    float* deviceData2;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceData1, length * sizeof(unsigned short));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceData2, length * sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(deviceData1, pixels1, length * sizeof(unsigned short), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceData2, pixels2, length * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int  threads = 1024; //my maximum
    int blocks = (length / threads); // lenght=1280*960 -> blocks=1200

    VecAdd<<< blocks, threads >>>( deviceData1, deviceData2,  length, div );

    cudaMemcpy(pixels2, deviceData2, length * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree( deviceData1 );
    cudaFree( deviceData2 );
    }`
```

and I do

```
float* avrg2f = (float*)malloc( width * height * sizeof(float));
memset( avrg2f, 0.0, sizeof(float) * width * height);

for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {           
 imageObjectList.at( curObj )->getImage( k );
 kernel_wrapper( avrg1, avrg2f, height * width, (float)count);  
}
```

as result may averaged image will be in avrg2f;

Thank you.

Comment: You dont need `__syncthreads` in the kernel.

Comment: Yep, I know, thanks, but it's not affect at all.

Comment: Your method seems reasonable.  The averaging operation is of low compute intensity, and so likely any algorithm would be memory bandwidth bound.  For large image sizes (e.g. 1280x960 ~4MB) I don't see any obvious opportunities for further refinement.  You might pre-compute the inverse of the divider (i.e. 1/`count`) and turn it into a multiply in the kernel.  Why do you say this code looks unoptimal?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try with 1/count. I look nonoptimal for me because it tooks same time as CPU(openMP) code. And because I have used too many cudamalloc/cudaMemcpy. May be it will be more efficient to split my arrays and copy big block to GPU (to shared memory) and performs cals with this big blocks of arrays?

Comment: The cost to transfer the data from CPU to GPU could make this a relatively unattractive operation to perform on the GPU, again largely because the algorithm is memory-bound.  To some extent this may be affected by what kind of GPU you are running on, and possibly by what kind of PCIE link it is attached to your system.  Shared memory might be an option, but overall it would require a substantial re-write to your algorithm, and imply that all the images are loaded at once.  4MB * 20,000 might make this impractical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are all the same size, then your wrapper function need not do `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` operations on every call.

Pre-allocate that storage needed, and don't allocated and free it on every call to the wrapper.

In addition you may see something like a ~2x speedup (for the `cudaMemcpy` operations) if you use pinned allocations (`cudaHostAlloc`) on the host side for your image storage.

Finally, for the duration of your loop, there's no need to copy the results back to the host.  Do this after you're done computing the average.  This will save 2 out of the 3 `cudaMemcpy` operations you are doing in the wrapper.

While we're at it, in my opinion using `memset` to initialize a `float` array is questionable.  It works for a zero value, but essentially no other.  Furthermore, I would expect passing `0.0` as the second parameter to `memset` to at least throw a compiler warning.

The following code shows the above optimizations, and demonstrates about an 8x speedup over your code in my test case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

__global__ void VecAdd(unsigned short *A, float *B,  unsigned int Size, float div){

  register float divider = div;
  register int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if ( idx < Size) {
   B[ idx ] = (float) A[idx] /  divider + B[idx];
  }
  //__syncthreads();
}

__global__ void VecAdd2(unsigned short *A, float *B,  unsigned int Size, float mult){

  register int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if ( idx < Size) {
   B[ idx ] = (float) A[idx] * mult + B[idx];
  }
}

void kernel_wrapper(unsigned short* pixels1, float* pixels2,  unsigned int length, float div)
{
    unsigned short* deviceData1;
    float* deviceData2;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceData1, length * sizeof(unsigned short));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceData2, length * sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(deviceData1, pixels1, length * sizeof(unsigned short), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceData2, pixels2, length * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int  threads = 1024; //my maximum
    int blocks = (length / threads); // lenght=1280*960 -> blocks=1200

    VecAdd<<< blocks, threads >>>( deviceData1, deviceData2,  length, div );

    cudaMemcpy(pixels2, deviceData2, length * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree( deviceData1 );
    cudaFree( deviceData2 );
    }
void kernel_wrapper2(unsigned short* h_pixels1, unsigned short* d_pixels1, float* d_pixels2,  unsigned int length, float my_mult)
{


    cudaMemcpy(d_pixels1, h_pixels1, length * sizeof(unsigned short), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int  threads = 1024; //my maximum
    int blocks = (length / threads); // lenght=1280*960 -> blocks=1200

    VecAdd2<<< blocks, threads >>>( d_pixels1, d_pixels2,  length, my_mult );

    }

int main(){

  const int count = 2000;
  const int width = 1280;
  const int height = 960;
  timeval t1, t2;
  unsigned long et;

  unsigned short *h1_image;
  h1_image = (unsigned short *)malloc(height*width*sizeof(unsigned short));

  float* avrg2f = (float*)malloc( width * height * sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i<height*width; i++){
    h1_image[i] = (i%256);
    avrg2f[i] = 0.0f;
    }

  gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
  for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
    kernel_wrapper( h1_image, avrg2f, height * width, (float)count);
  }
  gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);
  et = ((t2.tv_sec * 1000000)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec * 1000000) + t1.tv_usec);
  printf("time 1 = %ld us\n", et);
  unsigned short *h2_image;
  float* avrg3f = (float*)malloc( width * height * sizeof(float));
  cudaHostAlloc((void **)&h2_image, height*width*sizeof(unsigned short), cudaHostAllocDefault);
  for (int i = 0; i<height*width; i++){
    h2_image[i] = (i%256);
    avrg3f[i] = 0.0f;
    }
  gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
  unsigned short *d_image;
  float *d_result;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_image, height*width*sizeof(unsigned short));
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, height*width*sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpy(d_result, avrg3f, height*width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
    kernel_wrapper2( h2_image, d_image,  d_result, height * width, (float)(1/(float)count));
  }
  cudaMemcpy(avrg3f, d_result, height*width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);
  et = ((t2.tv_sec * 1000000)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec * 1000000) + t1.tv_usec);
  printf("time 2 = %ld us\n", et);
  for (int i = 0; i < (height*width); i++)
    if (fabs(avrg2f[i] - avrg3f[i]) > 0.0001) {printf("mismatch at %d, 1 = %f, 2 = %f\n", i, avrg2f[i], avrg3f[i]); return 1;}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Robert, I got your idea!

Comment: You can further optimize this by overlapping the `cudaMemcpy` operation with the compute (kernel) operation, using streams.